# How to sort Map<String, Map<String, int>> Dart

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

I would love to sort value of Map inside the main Map

```
var data = { 
'Data 1' : {'people': 200, 'disctrict': 20},
'Data 2' : {'people': 300, 'disctrict': 12},
'Data 3' : {'people': 520, 'disctrict': 10},
};
```

Now I want to sort based on `people` value.

So the expected result should be like this:

```
var data = { 
'Data 3' : {'people': 520, 'disctrict': 10},
'Data 2' : {'people': 300, 'disctrict': 12},
'Data 1' : {'people': 200, 'disctrict': 20},
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably much better solutions out there, but something like this. You'll have to convert the map to a list to sort it.

```
void main() {
  var data = { 
    'Data 1' : {'people': 200, 'disctrict': 20},
    'Data 2' : {'people': 300, 'disctrict': 12},
    'Data 3' : {'people': 520, 'disctrict': 10},
  };

  print('unsorted: $data');

  List<Map<String,dynamic>> listData = [];
  data.forEach((key, value) => listData.add({key: value}));

  listData.sort((a, b) {
    int aValue = a.values.first["people"];
    int bValue = b.values.first["people"];
    print('a values: $aValue');
   print('b values: $bValue');
    return aValue < bValue ? 1 : 0;
  });

  var sortedMap = Map.fromIterable(listData, key: (e) => e.keys.first, value: (e) => e.values.first);

 print('sorted: $sortedMap');
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Can you tell me what is used of these lines of code `int aValue = a.values.first["people"];
    int bValue = b.values.first["people"];` and `return aValue < bValue ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: So the idea is that you need to tell the sort function how you want the list to be sorted with a comparator. There are tons of sorting algorithms out there, and they work by comparing numbers. When two numbers are compared, they decide where to put a number. That's kind of a simplification, but you can look up what algorithm dart uses. For convenience, first I declare two variables to store the two values that I want to compare. Think of aValue < bValue ? 1 : 0; as if I'm comparing two values in the list, if one is bigger than the other, should it go higher or lower on the list?

Comment: glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is a `LinkedHashMap` and stores entries in insertion order.  If you want a different order, you will need to use [`Map.entries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map-class.html), convert it to a `List`, sort it, and then add them to a new `Map` (or clear the old one and add to that).  Something like:

```dart
var mapEntries = data.entries.toList();
mapEntries.sort((a, b) => b.value['people'].compareTo(a.value['people']));
data = Map.fromEntries(mapEntries);
```